# Google Search return results on page - HTML

Tags: html, search-engine

I know this might have been asked before but I couldn't find anything that relates directly to my question or anything that would help me so please don't mark this as a duplicate. My question is that I have a google search box on my web site(learning html on a website hosted on my raspberry pi) and anyway what I want is to have that search return results in my page not redirect to google. Here's what I have so far:

```
<div id="search"> 
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search"> 
<fieldset> 
<input type="text" name="q" id="search-text" size="15" /> 
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Google" /> 
</fieldset> 
</form>
```

I'm pretty sure this is possible just not sure how.

Comment: I know this is possible through AdSense. Not sure inside your site though...maybe in a frame?

Comment: I'm only 17 not really interested in earning any money

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for-

https://www.google.com/cse/

It's called Google Custom Search engine and the basic version is free to use.  It will localize the search to your website.

On the info page it says

> you choose the colors, location of the ads, **and the option to host the results on your site or have Google host them for you.**

Hope this helps!